# C/C++ change a define to a variable

Tags: c++, c, variables

Simple question:

How do you change #define TIMER_MAX 0xFFFF ; into a const variable? I'm unsure as to what type to use. Is it a byte?

Thanks

Comment: Those are two bytes, so maybe - `uint16_t timer_max = 0xFFFF;`

Comment: Or just int. Depends on the context it's used in I'd say.

Comment: If it worked fine before as `int`, might as well keep it as an `int`.

Comment: @bstamour It was never an `int`.  A macro has no inherent type.  At each place the preprocessor encounters `TIMER_MAX`, that string is replaced by `0xFFFF`.  The compiler never sees `TIMER_MAX`, only the constant `0xFFFF`, so it applies the appropriate rules for coercion, etc. to that constant.

Comment: @sfstewman: It has a type and it was int. Integer literals (even those expressed in Hex) are of type int unless suffixed by u and or l etc.

Answer (score 6):

It needs **2** bytes and [`uint16_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) is suitable:

```
#include <cstdint>

const uint16_t TimerMax = 0xFFFF;
```

Comment: Only thing I would do differently is mark it as `constexpr` so that it can be used for compile-time programming if neeeded.

Comment: @bstamour: scalar variables marked `const` which are initialized from constant expressions are constant expressions.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley This is true in C++, but I don't believe it is for C, and the question is tagged for both.  Of course, C has no `constexpr` modifier.

Answer (score 3):

```
const unsigned TimerMax = 0xFFFF;
```

Should do just fine.  Unless you need `TimerMax` to be of a *specific* size.

Comment: If your int is only 16 bits (which is allowed by the standard), what then?  You have to make it at least an unsigned int.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a byte.  A byte has 8-bits, and thus supports unsigned values from 0-255.

The value 0xFFFF requires at least a 16-bit value.  I would make this into an enum constant and let the compiler choose the appropriate size:

```
enum { TimerMax = 0xFFFF };
```

This has the advantage that it will be treated as a compile-time constant in both C and C++.  It also, for better or worse, maintains the macro property that you cannot take the memory location of `TimerMax`.

It's arguably less readable than using a const variable, but it's such a common idiom in C that I don't find this to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a `#define` macro into a variable, whether it's `const` or not. Macros and variables declaration belong to two completely different stages of the compilation process. The macros are expanded by the pre-processor, while the variables are allocated during the semantic analyse of the code. So, only do that if you really know the code you are working at.

Comment: #defines are often used just as global const values, that aren't referenced by any other preprocessor expression. So you can replace them as const variables, and in these cases, it is actually recommended to do so.

Comment: The OP wants to change it when he's writing the code (I think). So he can delete the macro and put something else.

Answer (score 0):

It would be 2 bytes, so a short.

You could define it as follows:

```
const unsigned short TimerMax = 0xFFFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a char(1 byte) or short(2 bytes) both sizes are dependent on machine implementation though, and declare it in hex if you want.

```
unsigned short hex_num = 0xFFFF; // 0xFFFF is 2 bytes
```